# C# reference object still alive after GC.Collect

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

On statement var `list = Foo();` CLR executing `Library = null;` after stepping in debug mode on line `GC.Collect(2)`; list is still have 10 elements. Why it does no set to null? For which object it executing `Library = null;`?

```
public class Book
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Controller : IDisposable
{
    public List<Book> Library = null;

    public Controller()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Controller created.");
        Console.WriteLine("List created.");
        Library = new List<Book>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Library.Add(new Book { FirstName = "FirstName" + i.ToString(), LastName = "LastName" + i.ToString() });
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Library = null; // Just for check
        Console.WriteLine("List disposed.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static List<Book> Foo()
    {
        using (var lib = new Controller())
        {
            return lib.Library;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = Foo();
        GC.Collect(0);
        GC.Collect(1);
        GC.Collect(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The GC (1) makes no guarantees about obeying your request to perform a collection when you call `GC.Collect`, and (2) behaves differently when you have a debugger attached.

Comment: How are you checking that list after you remove all references to it?

Comment: @JoeSewell, okay than why list in Main function is not null? I set him with null in dispose method.

Comment: @AlexGorbunov You didn't, you set the property that had a reference to the list to null, but this doesn't affect any other variables or properties that may have gotten that reference.

Comment: I think you're confused about how reference types work. If you do `var x = new List<int>(); var y = x; x = null;`, then `x` is `null`, but `y` is still referring to the list. Think of the list as an object taking up memory somewhere. Then `x` and `y` are just *referring* to that location in memory. If you set one of them to `null`, it no longer points there, but that doesn't change what was at that memory location, so the other one is still referring to a `List<int>`. And the `GC` won't dispose of something if there is an active reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"For which object it executing `Library = null;`?"*

`Dispose` is called automatically at the end of a `using` block, so this code is where `Library` is set to `null`:

```
private static List<Book> Foo()
{
    using (var lib = new Controller())
    {
        return lib.Library;
    } // <-- Dispose is called here on 'lib'
}
```

Note that this is called *after* a reference is obtained to `Library` for the `return` statement, so the method still returns a valid reference.

And because a reference to the list was returned (and not a null reference), that is why `list` is not `null`.

---

If you purposefully called `Dispose` *before* getting the reference, then `Library` will be `null`:

```
private static List<Book> Foo()
{
    using (var lib = new Controller())
    {
        lib.Dispose();
        return lib.Library;  // Now 'Library' is null
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Foo()` returns a reference to the list of books created in `Controller`, and that reference is stored in the variable `list`. The garbage collector will not collect the list of books because it is still being referred to by your program. The list of books will be garbage collected when there are no variable containing a reference to it.

If you call `Foo()` without storing the return value, then the list of books will be marked for garbage collection, and will be collected eventually when the garbage collector runs.